# Rutas 'Cannot Match' con Angular 6

Tags: angular, rutas, angular6

Estoy tratando de armar una pagina, para no hacerlo muy complicado voy a decir que tengo tres componentes un menu (mainComponent) y otros dos componentes llamados bajo(bajoComponent) y guitarras(guitarraComponent).

Quiero que el menu con dos botones para ir a los componentes bajo y guitarras, desaparezca. No quiero que el menu me funcione como un navbar que siempre esta presente, quiero que desaparezca cuando me muevo al componente guitarra o bajo.

Yo tengo mi archivo (que me creo angular) app-routing-module.ts con este contenido:

```
import { MainComponent } from './components/main/main.component';
import { MenuBajoComponent } from './components/menu-bajo/menu-bajo.component';
import { MenuGuitarraComponent } from './components/menu-guitarra/menu-guitarra.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
  path:'menu',
  component: MainComponent,
  },
  {
    path:'bajo',
    component: MenuBajoComponent
  },
  {
    path:'guitarra',
    component: MenuGuitarraComponent
  }
];
```

Asi estoy usando las rutas en el main component:

```
<div>
    <li routerLinkActive="active">
        <a routerLink="menubajo">Bajo</a>
    </li>
    <li routerLinkActive="active">
        <a routerLink="menuguitarra">Guitarra</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

Y el app.component.html esta simplemente con el router-outlet

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Cuando yo estoy en /menu funciona bien, pero cuando me muevo a uno de los componentes guitarra o bajo me tira este error

```
core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'menu/bajo'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'menu/bajo'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo solucione... en los routersLink tenia que escribirlo asi:

```
<a routerLink="/bajo">Bajo</a>
```

Con el `/`, NO asi:

```
<a routerLink="bajo">Bajo</a>
```

Y con eso lo pude arreglar.